# Swift Bar Button Item 360 Spin?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have seen similar questions on here before, but they relate to just simple buttons, not bar button items. Keep in mind- bar button items and regular buttons have different properties, thus the answers on the other posts will not work in this situation.

Is there a way, in swift, that I can make my refresh bar button item spin 360 degrees one time (to show that an action occurred)?

Comment: @ZGski CMON I literally said why it was different in my question and you still mark it as a duplicate. I have tried the answers on that post but Bar Button Items and regular buttons have different properties (i.e. transform) so the answers don't work!

Comment: Does your `barButtonItem` contain a custom image or view?

Comment: @ZGski no it doesn't, it is just a standard bar button item using apple's refresh icon that I set in the interface builder

Comment: You are correct that it's a bit different than the post I referenced. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to animate a `UIBarButtonItem`, we need to assign it a `customView` and animate that instead.

What I've done below is create an ordinary `UIButton`, and I've assigned it's image to a refresh icon named *"refresh"*. Next, I set my `UIBarButtonItem`'s `customView` to be my new button. Now that `barButton` has a `customView`, I can call my `rotateBarButton()` method to perform the animation code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var barButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)) // Create new button & set its frame
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "refresh"), forState: .Normal) // Assign an image 
        barButton.customView = button // Set as barButton's customView
    }

    func rotateBarButton() {
        // Gets you half way there //
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.05, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.barButton.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
            }, completion: nil)
        // Rotates all the way around //
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.barButton.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI * 2))
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It actually didn't solve the problem, I tried it on a standard button and it worked but it did not do anything for the bar button item unfortunately

Comment: I ended up showing an alert instead of rotating the button

Comment: It's not a matter of what was used in the end, it's more about if another user is looking to have the same question answered, they can trust that this response works.

Comment: Yeah but like I said the reason I didn't use it in the end is because it did not work...

Comment: I'll check it anyway if you want me to though... maybe it is something I did wrong when coding it